# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject boolean always false

Tags: c#, json.net

Why does the code below returns `false` for `showStatusbar`?

I'm trying to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert a Json file.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonData = "{\"Settings\": [{\"networkDeviceDiscovery\": \"supported\"},{\"showStatusbar\":true}]}";

            Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonData);

            Console.WriteLine("NetworkDeviceDiscovery: {0}", myDeserializedClass.Settings[0].NetworkDeviceDiscovery);
            Console.WriteLine("ShowStatusbar: {0}", myDeserializedClass.Settings[0].ShowStatusbar);
        }
    }

    public class Setting
    {
        [JsonProperty("networkDeviceDiscovery")]
        public string NetworkDeviceDiscovery;

        [JsonProperty("showStatusbar")]
        public bool ShowStatusbar;
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("Settings")]
        public List<Setting> Settings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `"{\"Settings\": [{\"networkDeviceDiscovery\": \"supported\",\"showStatusbar\":true}]}"`? (you have a pair of `{}` too many)

Comment: Indeed, although this is what I have to deal with as this json is returned by a third party device ... also, when checked in JSONLint this Json is valid ...

Comment: Is there any ways to deal with this JSON as is?

Comment: Do you happen to have some API documentation from that third party? Are you sure the two objects in the array should be seen as one?

Comment: json2csharp does no complain about this JSON formating and generate code properly

Comment: API is here: https://wolfvision.com/wolf/commands_cynap_wolfvision/protocol/commands_cynap.html (Extra Settings File command) but they are not documenting much on what they are returning. The objects can be seen a whatever I want as long as I can retrieve the data... Although it's returning much more that that so that will do quite a lot of objects if I have to use one for each

Comment: `myDeserializedClass.Settings[1].ShowStatusbar` returns `true` ... it because there are 2 objects in the settings list: first with values `"supported", false`, second with `null, true`

Comment: Indeed, and I guess the next object will be stored in myDeserializedClass.Settings[2]... Doesn't look like the proper way to handle this though ...

Comment: yes,  `string jsonData = "{\"Settings\": [{\"networkDeviceDiscovery\": \"supported\"},{\"showStatusbar\":false},{\"streamingInterface\": \"lan\"}]}";

            Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonData);

            Console.WriteLine("NetworkDeviceDiscovery: {0}", myDeserializedClass.Settings[0].NetworkDeviceDiscovery);
            Console.WriteLine("ShowStatusbar: {0}", myDeserializedClass.Settings[1].ShowStatusbar);
            Console.WriteLine("StreamingInterface: {0}", myDeserializedClass.Settings[2].StreamingInterface);` is working

Comment: so the only other ways to handle this is to create a specific class for each one of these? which would mean that json2csharp is not handling this properly ... ?

Comment: no, it means that json is badly designed.. settings should be rather `Dictionary<string, object>` ... you may try to fix it by deserialize it to `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` then flat it to single  `Dictionary<string, object>` with `SelectMany` + `ToDictionary`

Comment: [like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vDpGDU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure we're on the same page, this is the JSON you're dealing with:

```
{
  "Settings": [
    {
      "networkDeviceDiscovery": "supported"
    },
    {
      "showStatusbar": true
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see there are two separate objects which means the two properties `networkDeviceDiscovery` and `showStatusbar` only appear in one each. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BwIZiV) for a demonstration.

Without having more information about the origin of that JSON, what I can suggest is to adjust your `Setting` class to make all properties nullable, so that you can identify when a property is actually appearing in the JSON or not:

```
public class Setting
{
    [JsonProperty("networkDeviceDiscovery")]
    public string NetworkDeviceDiscovery;

    [JsonProperty("showStatusbar")]
    public bool? ShowStatusbar;
}
```

Now, when deserializing the properties are null whenever they don't appear in the JSON. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f3et7p). This makes it easier now for you to combine the list of `Settings` into one `Setting object`:

```
// ...
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonData);

var resultSettings = new Setting();
foreach (var setting in myDeserializedClass.Settings)
{
    if (setting.ShowStatusbar.HasValue)
    {
        resultSettings.ShowStatusbar = setting.ShowStatusbar;
    }
    // Continue with the other properties...
}
```

See [this final fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x8bIl9).

Yes, this is very tedious if there are a lot of properties, but I don't see a much better solution. You could make it more scalable using reflection if you want to dig into that.

Note: I cannot guarantee this solution is in line with the thoughts behind whoever created that API. But as @Selvin mentions, it's probably due to a bad design of the JSON model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the braces wrong. Try this:

```
string jsonData = "{\"Settings\": [{\"networkDeviceDiscovery\": \"supported\",\"showStatusbar\":true}]}";
```

Comment: Indeed, although this is what I have to deal with as this json is returned by a third party device ... also, when checked in JSONLint this Json is valid ...